# In Magento ,I cant upload the image in the products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In magneto when i create the new products. I cant upload the product image. That page shows error like this

"Image type and information need to be specified for each store view. "

I cleared the Cache Storage but i also face this issue. Please help to solve this issue[image: Cant Upload the products image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this problem is browser based (corrupted flash player plugin)

Checklist suggested for it:

1. Check in another browser, if it is working try to reset the browser where it is giving problem.
2. missing /media directory or if /media directory has no write permission.
3. prototype js version is also causes this but rarely. (Only when you are doing up gradation or installing incompatible magento extension)

Let me know which one is working for you.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefinedFlex.getFlashPlayerVersion @ flex.js:164Flex.checkFlashPlayerVersion @ flex.js:46Flex.Object.Class.create.detectFlashVersion @ flex.js:425Flex.Object.Class.create.initialize @ flex.js:200klass @ prototype.js:101Flex.Uploader.initialize @ flexuploader.js:63klass @ prototype.js:101(anonymous function) @ (index):1627 (index):1645Uncaught ReferenceError: id_186adf861e7a54cc91b1594e53a002b5_UploaderJsObject is not defined - Error shows in console.

Comment: did you try in different browser ... please mention the name of browser you have tried. and also try to reset the browser once.

Comment: either update the flash player to latest stable version or disable for time being and check it.

Comment: Issue solved I used different browser. First i used chrome. Now i use mozilla

Comment: i have same issue, fixed by @hakan's answare.

Comment: @SuyashKumarBharti I am using your code : https://justpaste.it/1g2v4 from : http://www.justcode.in/2014/02/how-to-export-and-import-categories-in.html,  My question : How can i filter by store or root category.

Answer (score 16):

I fixed problem below. I found solution from google.

- Go chrome settings,
- chrome://settings/content
- Content settings flash
- Choose Allow sites

This solution fixed my problem.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well, except that I added my site to the list of "allowed", instead of just allowing every site

Comment: This fixed mine too, at least in normal chrome browser, but not in incognito

Comment: Now it is by clicking the padlock icon by the url > site settings > flash (allow) seems chrome changed how to add exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t upload images for a product in your admin section of magento it may have something to do with your flash plugin in your browser.Please disable Flash in your browser.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefinedFlex.getFlashPlayerVersion @ flex.js:164Flex.checkFlashPlayerVersion @ flex.js:46Flex.Object.Class.create.detectFlashVersion @ flex.js:425Flex.Object.Class.create.initialize @ flex.js:200klass @ prototype.js:101Flex.Uploader.initialize @ flexuploader.js:63klass @ prototype.js:101(anonymous function) @ (index):1627
(index):1645Uncaught ReferenceError: id_186adf861e7a54cc91b1594e53a002b5_UploaderJsObject is not defined - Error shows in console.

Comment: I think it may have to do with Magento more than flash in the browser itself. Flash's browsers works in all cases. Only in counted Magentos' store it brings this problem. It has to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use Magento HTML5 Uploader Extension. Extension link is below:  https://marketplace.magento.com/mavenecommerce-html5-uploader.html

Answer (score -1):

Just add those tags in layout file you can find solution here [fixed](http://magento-slution.blogspot.ru/2017/08/mageno-referenceerror-uploader-is-not.html)